# when i fetch data from data base it gives unique data but when i print on <h:datatable> using jsf it is print data with duplicate data

Tags: jsf, jdbc, primefaces

when i fetch data from data base with distinct key word it gives unique or single data but when i print on  using jsf it is print data with duplicate every logging time.

bean :-Privilege.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "privilegeBean", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class Privilege {

private int id;
private String privilege;
public List<Privilege> messages;
private PrivilegeDao prvlgdao=new PrivilegeDao();
private boolean canEdit;
private Privilege privilegeedit;
private String str;

public Privilege() {

    messages = new ArrayList<Privilege>();
}

public Privilege(int id, String privilege) {
    this.id = id;
    this.privilege = privilege;
    this.canEdit = false;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPrivilege() {
    return privilege;
}

public void setPrivilege(String privilege) {
    this.privilege = privilege;
}

public List<Privilege> getMessages() {
    this.messages = prvlgdao.getUserList();
    return messages;
}

public void setMessages(List<Privilege> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}

public boolean isCanEdit() {
    return canEdit;
}

public void setCanEdit(boolean canEdit) {
    this.canEdit = canEdit;
}

public String editPrivilege() {
    privilegeedit.setCanEdit(true);
    return null;
}

public String addPrivileges() {
    int ins = prvlgdao.insertPrivilege(privilege);
    if (ins == 1) {
        System.out.println("privilege is insert ........");
        str="1";
    }
    return str;
}
}
```

Dao :-PrivilegeDao

```
public class PrivilegeDao {
private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/city_info";
private static final String DB_USER = "root";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";
private static Connection dbConnection = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
private String sqlprivilege;
private int pinsert;
private ResultSet rs=null;
private List<Privilege> list = new ArrayList<Privilege>();
private Privilege prg;

private static Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    try {

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,
                DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    return dbConnection;

}

public List<Privilege> getUserList()
{
    try
    {
        //list=null;
        prg=new Privilege();
        sqlprivilege = "select distinct privilege from privilege";
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        // execute select SQL stetement
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlprivilege);
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            prg.setPrivilege(rs.getString("privilege"));
            list.add(prg);
            System.out.println("user id is ......");

        }


    }
    catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            try {
                dbConnection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    return list;

}
}
```

xhtml :- Privilege.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable value="#{privilegeBean.messages}" var="u"
        id="datatbldispprivilege">

        <p:column headerText="Privileges">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{u.privilege}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <br />

    <h3>Add Employee</h3>
    <hr />
    <h:panelGrid id="pnlgrdlogin">
        <p:column headerText="Add Privileges">
            <p:inputText value="#{privilegeBean.privilege}" name="txtprivilege" /><br>    </br><br></br>
            <p:commandButton name="btmaddprivilege" value="Add Privilege"
                action="privilegeBean.addPrivileges" />
        </p:column>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

html file display duplicate data using data table and mysql data contain one table  "privilege" and two attribute "id","privilege" .

when i fetch record from data base it give 1 record but when i print it it gives 2,3,4,5... records every logging time.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `public List<Privilege> getUserList()` on your class `PrivilegeDao` you add all records to `list` and return this list. 
Creating a local list in your method `public List<Privilege> getUserList()` will solve this problem.

```
public List<Privilege> getUserList()
{
    List<Privilege> localList = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        // ...
        while(rs.next())
        {
            prg.setPrivilege(rs.getString("privilege"));
            localList.add(prg);
        }
    }
    // ...
    return localList;
}
```